# change variable so $F$ transform into a separable variable equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, change-of-variable

I was studying ODE (with a book by Sotomayor) and I got stuck with this one problem.

Let $$\frac{dx}{dt}=F \left(\frac{at + bx+c}{dt+ex+f} \right)\tag{$*$}$$

where $a,b,c,d,e,f$ is constants. If $ae=bd$, then find a change of variables such that transform $(*)$ into a separable variable equation (i.e. $\frac{dx}{dt}=F(t)H(x)$ or $\frac{dx}{dt}=G(t)F(x)$ ).

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: If $ae=bd$ then $(a, b)$ and $(d, e)$ are linearly dependent, say $(a, b)=K(d, e)$ for some $K\ne 0$. With the change of variable $x\to x/K, t\to t/K, $ the problem turns into $$\frac{dx}{dt}=F\left( \frac{at+bx+c}{at+bx+f}\right).$$ Not sure if this helps

Comment: Now, if $a=0$ or $b=0$ we are done. If not, setting $s=at+bx, y=ax$ does the trick.

Comment: it definitely helped me @GiuseppeNegro! thanks a lot!!